# Toastr message rendering issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, toastr

I am having difficulty getting Toastr to work within my application.

Right now I have the following code that I wrote so that Toastr error messages would occur if a user did not input the correct information into form fields.

```
<% unless resource.errors.empty? %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            toastr.error('<%= msg %>')
        <% end %>
    </script>
<% end %>
```

I also have this code that I am using for flash messages, but when I try to sign in and out they are not appearing

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <% flash.each do |f| %>
            <% type = f[0].to_s.gsub('alert','error').gsub('notice','info') %>
            toastr['<%= type %>']('<%= f[1] %>')
        <% end %>
    </script>
<% end %>
```

I am rendering the code in the necessary views and I have the toastr gem installed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where everything set properly except `toastr`. Once change JavaScript tag position, it worked fine.

Usually I would add the JavaScript include tag before `</body>` tag, which is advisable for performance.
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

In this case `toaster` worked when JS tag moved within `head` tag with css tag.

Hope it works for you.